# Clarification of sequence limits property

Tags: limits

I am worried about how the following property of sequence limits is written

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_n}{b_n} = 
\frac{ \lim_{n \to \infty} a_n}{\lim_{n \to \infty} b_n} 
\text{ if } \exists \lim_{n \to \infty} a_n, \lim_{n \to \infty} b_n \text{ and } \lim_{n \to \infty} b_n \neq 0
$$

But I can't understand why is it not written that $b_n \neq 0, \forall n \in \Bbb{N}$. Explain to me pls.

Comment: We don't need the $b_n$ to all be different from $0$.  We only need the fact that starting from a given $N$, for all $n>N$, $b_n\neq0$. Which is equivalent to $\lim_{n\to\infty}b_n\neq 0$.

Comment: I think $b_n\neq 0$ is not stated because it is implicitly meant. However, we **must** have $b_n\neq 0$, otherwise the ratio $\frac{a_n}{b_n}$ is not defined when $b_n = 0$.